# How to acquire more than one lock atomically in Java?

Tags: java

A common pattern in Java to acquire more than one lock is like this:

```
synchronized (lock1) {
...
   synchronized(lock2) {
   }
}
```

This is a common cause of deadlocks, because if another thread has the order reversed i.e.:

```
synchronized (lock2) {
...
   synchronized(lock1) {
   }
}
```

then no thread will be able to proceed. Both are blocked indefinitely.

C++ provides a [scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) construct to acquire more than one lock atomically:

> When a scoped_lock object is created, it attempts to take ownership of the mutexes it is given. When control leaves the scope in which the scoped_lock object was created, the scoped_lock is destructed and the mutexes are released. If several mutexes are given, deadlock avoidance algorithm is used as if by std::lock.

Does Java have such a thing?

Comment: One solution is 'don't do that'.  Always acquire locks in  a specific order; this is manageable with a small, fixed number of locks (or at least, the case where you don't ever hold 2 locks of tthe same rank).

Comment: Two phase locking is a well established protocol (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking). Or you could consider the locks as a group to be a resource, and wrap them in an object to manage them - in practice, have a "master lock" that you need before you can lock or unlock any of the group, then release it.

Comment: Short answer is "no". At least I'm not aware of anything comparable in the standard library.  When I implemented my own, the locks were expressed as strings. That way I could sort them and thus grab them consistently in the same order.  `Object::wait` and `Object::notifyAll` did the rest.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Java have such a thing?

You cannot do this with Java primitive mutexes; i.e. `synchronized`.
But if you use `Lock` objects rather than primitive mutexes, you can implement that kind of behavior using `Lock.tryLock`.  For example.

```
Lock lock1 ...
Lock lock2 ...

lock1.lock();  // This blocks until the lock is acquired
try {
    if (lock2.tryLock()) {  // NB: this does not block ... so no deadlock
       try {
          // Do stuff
       } finally {
          lock2.unlock();
       } 
    } else {
       System.out.println("Potential deadlock avoided!");
    }
} finally {
    lock1.unlock();
}
```

Note that you must use *try ... finally* for this.  Since a `Lock` is not auto-closable, *try with resource* won't release the lock.

For more details, refer to the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) for the `Lock` interface.

---

It is worth noting that while the above won't deadlock, there is still a (theoretical) risk of livelock where two threads loop the above code and repeatedly avoid the deadlock ... but make no actual progress.

As noted by a commenter, another way to avoid deadlock is to design the application so that pairs of locks are always acquired in the same order.